# Bash Exit Code Status script error

Tags: bash, exit-code

```
#!/bin/bash
# exitlab
#
# example of exit status
# check for non-existent file 
# exit status will be 2
# create file and check it
# exit status will be 0
#
ls xyzzy.345 > /dev/null 2>&1
status='echo $?'
echo "status is $status"

# create the file and check again
# status will not be 0
touch xyzzy.345

ls xyzzy.345 > /dev/null 2>&1
status='echo $?'
echo "status is $status"

#remove the file
rm xyzzy.345
```

edx.org has a Lab and this is the script. When I run it, the output is as follows:

```
status is echo $?
status is echo $?
```

I think the output is supposed to be either 0 or 2. I tried putting parentheses like `status='(echo $?)` but that results in `status is echo $?`. Then, I tried putting parentheses outside of the single quotes `status=( 'echo $?' )` but this gave me the same output `status is echo $?`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would use `echo "status is "$?`or `stt=$?; echo "status is "$stt`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use double-quotes here for the variable substitution to take place. Change

```
status='echo $?'
```

to

```
status="echo $?"
```

You might find this guide helpful: [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html)

Comment: Thank you. That produced the correct output `status is echo 2` and
`status is echo 0`. Please answer my question so I can give you points.

Comment: I am guessing that you are interested in how quotes work, and not in backticks. I have updated my answer. Single quotes protect the $ whereas double quotes allow substitution to take place. HTH

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for command substitution (`status=$(echo $?)`), although it isn't necessary. You can assign the value of `$?` directly to `status`:

```
status=$?
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the script the course on edx.org provided. Your advice makes sense for scripts I may need to use this for.